# Why is Google glog library not present in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

Bug Description: (Quoted from Bug Report)

"After the Precise Pangolin upgrade, it appears that libgoogle-glog-dev and libgoogle-glog0 are not available. Without the -dev package, asgard cannot be compiled. Without -glog0, it may not be dpkg'd. We should find a solution for this problem pretty fast."

I have posted this issue on the Ubuntu Forums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11970783#post11970783

*This directly effects at least 1 member of our team

This issue has been posted as a bug on Launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/asgard/+bug/999107

Answer (score 3):

[Also posted to bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/asgard/+bug/999107/comments/4)

1. Here's why it was pulled from Precise -- at the request of the Debian QA team: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libgoogle-glog0
2. If a ppa will do, 0.3.1-1ubuntu1 (from Oneiric) appears to compile just fine on Precise.